# How do I make my AlertDialog appear as soon as EditText has focus?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want my `AlertDialog` to pop up as soon as my `EditText` has focus. Right now, I have to click on my `EditText` twice.

The first time I click my `EditText`, the soft keypad appears (for typing directly in my `Edittext`). Then, the second time I click the `EditText`, the `AlertDialog` appears.

How can I have it so only one click on the `EditText` is needed for the `AlertDialog` to pop up?

Here's my code:

In my `onCreate`...

```
//when user clicks on "commentName" EditText we want a new AlertDialog to open
commentName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewContact.this);
    builder.setTitle("Ur Comment:");

    //start the following xml file/ layout
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(NewContact.this).inflate(R.layout.comment_text_pop_up, null, false);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
      }
    });

    builder.show();

  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried the `onFocusChange()` or the `onTouch()` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me, `OnTouchListener`:

```
 //when user clicks on "commentname" edittext we want a new textbox to open
    commentname.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewContact.this);
          builder.setTitle("Ur Comment:");

          //start the following xml file/ layout
          View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(NewContact.this).inflate(R.layout.comment_text_pop_up, null, false);
          builder.setView(viewInflated);

          // Set up the buttons
          builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.dismiss();
            }
          });
          builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              dialog.cancel();
            }
          });

          builder.show();
          return true;

        }
        return false;

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work according to your description with an OnFocusChangeListener.

Just replace the entire snippet from your question with the following. And paste in the AlertDialog code below the comment.

```
// commentName is your EditText
commentName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            return; // Prevents alert from being shown when losing focus.
        }
        // Your AlertDialog code goes here
    }
});
```

The `if (!hasFocus)` prevents the alert from being shown when the user clicks something else that makes the EditText lose focus.

Comment: Hey, great tip, thanks, wouldn't have got it working perfect if u hadn't put me on to different way with thinking. One issue with the above though - if user clicked 'Cancel' on the pop up, the edititext still has focus, then changes his mind to write again and clicks the edittext, the pop up doesn't appear...I solved it with setOnTouchListener.Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this with least code is by simply disabling focus on the `EditText`. You can do that by adding below attribute to your `EditText`...

```
<EditText
...
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"/>
```

Then set `OnClickListener` on your `EditText`, and show the dialog in `onClick()` method.